# How to hint boolean return type conditionally in TypeScript class methods?

Tags: typescript

In the following code sample, my goal is:

- Let `obj.isX` be `true` when `obj` constructed by type A
- Let `obj.isX` be `false` when `obj` constructed by type B

```
type A = { x: true };
type B = { x: false };

type AorB = A | B;

class MyClass<Input extends AorB> {
    _input: Input;

    constructor(input: Input) {
        this._input = input;
    }

    isX(): Input extends A ? true : false {
        return this._input.x;
    }
}
```

But I got `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Input extends A ? true : false'.(2322)`

TypeScript Playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUAeAuKwBOBXaAvgNwBQokUAQgsmpgGYCGANgM6GlnjQDCNcAHyqcAxs0atWUACIAeAKJQIqYBAB2AEyk8AfMhJRDUAPoRM8zkagiA9mtY5cI4DewAKM1HkBKfVavAABYAlqwAdKY0EKRWBCQGRqEAGm7e5koq6lqwUAD8WHjQDCzsfv6G2BDAuNhqWCHhpmGoMUZxBEA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
    isX(): E["x"] {
        return this._e.x;
    }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=6&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUAeAuKwBOBXaAvgNwBQokUAQgsmpgGYCGANgM6GlnjQDCNcAHyqcAxs0atWUACIAeAKJQIqYBAB2AEyk8AfMhJRDUAPoRM8zkagiA9mtY5cI4DewAKM1HkBKfVavAABYAlqwAdKY0EKRWBCQGRqEAGm7e5gDaAESomQC6fv6G2BDAuNhqWCHhpmGoMUZxcSQaEGKMxdZ2DlD0NjaYcjA6pC1tHbb2wFAARu0DspTDJBPd9DS9NmHJqURQAPR7PVChx2r0ENjFGlASWHgQy11T0zSz2FusKd67BzPHUsEzhcrjcpEw2BAgA)

Comment: Hi @Cameron Little, thanks you for the quick reply. Actually, this one is a simplified question I got. If you are still interested, I posted another question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61173834/how-to-hint-boolean-return-type-conditionally-in-a-string-check-typescript-class