# How to hint boolean return type conditionally in string check TypeScript class methods?

Tags: typescript

In the following code sample, my goal is:

- Let `obj.isMessage` be `true` when `obj` constructed by type Message
- Let `obj.isMessage` be `false` when `obj` constructed by type Unknown

```
type Message = { type: 'message' };
type Unknown = { type: 'unknown' };

type MorU = Message | Unknown;

class MyClass<Input extends MorU> {
    _input: Input;

    constructor(input: Input) {
        this._input = input;
    }

    isMessage(): Input extends A ? true : false {
        return this._input.type === 'message';
    }
}
```

But I got `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Input extends Message ? true : false'.(2322)`

TypeScript Playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBvKpIC4oByAWwWTSKgF8BuAKD2gFUA7Aa1YHsB3VqTDiaEiAVw7c+VOvUbhoMLgCdmA2OVTQAPlDaderBvQDGAGySJYIAMLnEAHgCSrMKOBQIAD2ARWAE3hYZWYAPmx6KEioAH0ASxc3QmdXYCMoqGMuVnhgJVFjYGUACniUpITgAEpw9PTgAAtY+AA6OIq1UrcGdOpZdKa4RE0iyvKUj29fAPUhtCgAflw86EIAMyRTeGgsCNrIpQhgUSV+BqbWzuBmpgF0TFINSm6o3t6TLJyoLgAjACs1VgQHhWWwWeBFITyERkWYQaSVBg-X7NAaPCAjWhAA

Comment: I don't think there's currently a way to do it exactly like that. My guess is that the best approach is to change the signature of `isMessage` to `isMessage(): boolean`.

Comment: What is the point of this conditional return type where you only want to return a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what the question specifically asks for, but I doubt that it'll be very useful to you.

---

Answer to the question as asked: the compiler is not good at verifying when a value is assignable to a conditional type that depends on an as-yet unspecified generic type parameter.  There is an open suggestion, [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), to do better in cases like this where you are trying to implement a function/method whose return type is an unresolved conditional type.  But for now it's not possible.

That means you need to tell the compiler yourself that what you're doing is safe, either with an assertion like `return ... as ...`; or by using a single-call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), like this:

```
isMessage(): Input extends Message ? true : false;
isMessage(): boolean {
    return this._input.type === 'message';
}
```

This will make the error go away; do note though that all this does is make the compiler take your word that you know what you're doing.  You could change the `===` in your function to `!==` and the compiler would still not complain.  So be careful.

---

The reason why I doubt it'll be useful is that having the *compiler* know that `obj.isMessage()` will be `true` and `obj2.isMessage()` will be `false` in the below code doesn't seem to buy you much:

```
const obj = new MyClass({ type: 'message' });
console.log(obj.isMessage()); // already know this is true

const obj2 = new MyClass({ type: 'unknown' });
console.log(obj2.isMessage()); // already know this is false
```

If you try to use this in a situation where *you* don't know which one an object is, then the compiler won't know either, and furthermore, it won't understand that when you check `isMessage()` it has any implications on the type:

```
const obj3 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? obj : obj2;
console.log(obj3.isMessage()); // just known as boolean now
if (obj3.isMessage()) {
    obj3._input.type // "message" | "unknown"
} else {
    obj3._input.type // "message" | "unknown"
}
```

The way in TypeScript to let the compiler understand that a check of something like `isMessage()` has an implication on the type is to use a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
    isMessage(): this is MyClass<Message> {
        return this._input.type === 'message';
    }
```

In this case, the compiler just treats the `isMessage()` result as `boolean`, but it will now understand the kind of check that we did with `obj3`:

```
const obj3 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? obj : obj2;
console.log(obj3.isMessage()); // just known as boolean now
if (obj3.isMessage()) {
    obj3._input.type // "message"
} else {
    obj3._input.type // "unknown"
}
```

This seems more useful to me, so that would be my suggestion in the absence of more context.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKaDWEAmSDeAUAUiUgC4CeMyAstFCAObIC8+5VEAXEgOSRQGzXkgC+AbmKlK1JAFVgGYAHsA7sCRs8Haj14BXRSvUiJRUjtrKATnM1I6gpsgA+8o2uCSpJeABsQQQcKAGEAwQAeAElgGH0yJAgADzIIYGwoBxs5AD58HwskAH0AS1j4nhi4sm9C0nhlYCgya314MhsACjLqyvKyAEp8urqyAAsSqAA6Uv77HvjJEbFzEcnHIQhOgb7qxJS0jId6ZyQAfnJW5B4AMxA-KAgltagN522eACNlZT8IEA0hGWFmsEDI+msGnGkxmCzIUxkrBYbH4J2EzzqogKWIKDSaCWUnwAVvZgBBVMEwoEoJ1tIi9AJNqYBhikHioL8IFM-MpGJ1CUSpus0VsBiykAB6CVIe6gkDYChIJRqcgTTKTS76CCrXyNZpIAUAJlJ5Mp4RpdM4ekMypMYhZuL1nO5vP5xMNQteIu24qlMr8coVSuMqo1GruD21jvxBuJAGZ7DQQOMptYAdhlGBtkgIkgAAxTACs51jJJ4RtZ7OdPL5ArjnrezB94kl0qJ+n1to0gSQ305AKQxgKJRuSDdRPrwqcTbFwxGddh-QRnFbSAARIznGukG41zbjMA19jEpG53UF7NqsvZH6NyLt7v954jxYcUQcaABHBEFlQXJHjc+h+GeljHNOrDsPSfCbsIYisoi7hdvYlq6HwT52mYBQITQ2SJiKO6IQetT1OaZrUtEczJKk6SZDhth5ECIyXhUSBVIsOqFOyLRtB01jdP0uzxEMjHAqG0zMQkbBwqyr4cRYU6bB8YlIBqNChOaESNhADEFMsoLgpCYmLleCHIiiMEQLwMmkG+snRvqAomhSalUoItKWAyIrMpWTp-C6tbEg23pii2fp9n8AIcVxpbGmwZLOep1LuVBBgeBhDoWFWfk1uOHoKe8IWruF-zAFFeoEvGibJmMqbppm2a5gWxYXI55buj5TTVq6C75TOvpth2CRIT2xUDkO8mjuOk5euBPogRYF5wteyC3hZL42SejzzaQi1Lght7oYe2LvkAA)